# Online physics collaboration tools

Tags: soft-question, software

I.e. online discussion with your friends. A forum is probably too overkill in this case.

Yet so far nothing can beat direct communication.
Important feature: the ability to archive discussions. We don't want to retell our story to people who just missed the "conference" (let the newcomers dig through the archives by themselves).

Comment: I stumbled upon convore because I desperately tried to find a nice google wave replacement.

Comment: If this is to stick around, it has to be CW as there is no one correct answer. Also, it would be much better to remove the suggestions from the question and post each one as a separate answer.

Comment: related http://blogs.nature.com/mfenner/2010/08/09/what-comes-after-google-wave

Comment: @pcr's link has rotted, here's the permalink: http://blogs.plos.org/mfenner/2010/08/09/what_comes_after_google_wave/

Comment: Tangential question over at TeX.SE: [Latex live preview plugin for Tiddlywiki ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8270/430)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should mention the wonderful userscripts written by [Valery Alexeev](http://alexeev.org/display-latex2.html) which utilize mathjax and allow you to render latex on *any* webpage, even if it does not support such rendering internally. Currently supported webpages include arXiv and gmail, though it should be easy to add your own to the list.

Used in combination with mathim.com and **Tiddlywiki** we have a powerful platform for online tex-enabled collaborations.

Comment: thank you for your userscript suggestion! with this, I could turn convore into "mathim.com" but with archive and topics.

Comment: @pcr have you succeeded in getting the userscript to work with convore? That would be sweet.

Comment: yes! that's why I was so excited.

Comment: What did you do? Just include the convore website address in the userscript?

Comment: yes. I managed to do that because in convore ["... everything is assembled at once: all messages, the sidebar, and the header are all rendered on the server instead of being pulled in after-the-fact with JavaScript"](http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/technology-behind-convore/)

Comment: Nice. I'll get back to you if I have any trouble ;) Cheers.

Comment: I still need to refresh my page in order to render new equations (not a big issue for me). hmm.. there seems to be a lot of hype around convore (especially among YCombinator hackers), so check it out. I think they'll implement the latex feature eventually, just like in quora.com

Comment: [alternative to Alexeev's script](http://thewe.net/tex/). it's cheaper bexause it uses another website to render the equations into images. also, I don't have to refresh my page anymore: new formula will be automatically rendered. quirk: they use [; and ;] as delimiter (I have to manually change it into $).

Comment: Ok I just tried it here https://convore.com/sciphysics/formulas-showcase/ and it is pretty sweet! Thanks again.

Comment: tiddlywiki+formulas+graph http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/asciencepad/asciencepad.html

Comment: Hi @pcr. Asciencepad renders MathML which is extremely tedious to enter. Bob McElrath's [jsmath plugin](http://bob.mcelrath.org/tiddlyjsmath-2.0.3.html) for TW, OTOH, allows you to enter latex directly into your text and renders it. For graphics I think MathSVG and Rafael are again better options. Asciencepad is a nice package but it does not seem suited for more technical and math oriented persons such as myself. Though, the jsmath plugin is getting to be four years old now and if it is not updated soon I might try another avenue.

Answer (score 3):

> http://www.mathim.com/

Latex based chatroom partially fulfills the requirement . The best scenario I can imagine is a mathjax/latex based wiki/website with an embedded $\LaTeX$ chat like M$\alpha$thIM.

Answer (score 2):

[convore](http://convore.com): $\frac1{\sqrt3}(|IRC\rangle + |mailing list\rangle + |chat\rangle)$

No built-in latex support yet, but this can be remedied by installing the [display latex](http://alexeev.org/display-latex2.html) userscript (thank you Deepak Vaid).

A nice complement to convore: online whiteboard (e.g. scriblink, flockdraw).

Comment: you can easily display images too!

Comment: dear pcr, you forgot a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ in the first line.

Comment: whoops! fixed. now it can freely evolve unitarily.

Comment: Convore has been replaced by something called [grove](https://grove.io/)

Answer (score 1):

alternative to tiddlywiki: [instiki](http://www.instiki.org/show/HomePage)

a simple wiki with latex support out of the box.

I haven't really explored it yet, so please share your experience.

Comment: I like tiddlywiki because of its modular nature. It doesn't have separate pages for each entry as instiki does. Instead it has separate "tiddlers" (an unfortunate choice of terminology, I know) all shown on one page. You can fold (collapse) tiddlers, rearrange them in any order and using some of the plugins available for TW even arrange tiddlers in *any* 2D pattern you care for. Visually, I think this provides a much more accessible tool for learning and note-keeping.

Comment: cool, I love TW's tag-based organization. Now I only need to convince my friend to switch to those new tools.

Answer (score 1):

Rather overkill, but you may want to try [MediaWiki](http://www.mesiawiki.org)

Requires: php/mysql
Install time:5  mins not counting download.

For math, there is an incredibly long procedure to set up the partially built-in png math renderer.

Alternatively, you can just install the mathjax extension. Quick process not including downloads.

Also, the LiquidThreads extension makes discussions easier and organized.

I'll post some links later.